# Run recorded Text to Column code on selected cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run the Text to Column function. I recorded a macro and it appears to work for the first attempt in the cell I recorded the macro for. I need this macro to run for any cells I select so I changed the range to "ActiveCell" but this seems to break the code.

Recorded Macro:

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("X32"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

works for me when I select a cell whose text have semicolons and it gets split into many columns

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `TextToColumns` to work, I hope you selected a single column as the source for this funtion to work, i.e selecting cells "E5:E10" will work.
Selecting multiple columns as an Input will result with a run-time error.

Documentation link [MSDN TextToColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx)

**Code**

```
Sub TxtToCol()

Dim DestRng     As Range

' setting the destination range using a variable
Set DestRng = Range("X32")

With Selection
    .TextToColumns Destination:=DestRng, _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=True, _
        Comma:=False, _
        Space:=False, _
        Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End With

End Sub
```